# Getting empty result in output when using Select statement in Grid-View

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Here what I have done
I make a `GridView` and choose the data key name as `id` and in the basis of id I want to show the `DetailsView`. Here the CS code

```
using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source= IA; initial catalog =aip; integrated Security=true;"))
{
    con1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Pm where user_id='" +(String)Session["uid"]+ "'", con1);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con1.Close();
}
```

Then I make `DetailsView` method on `SelectedIndexChanged`:
But it is showing empty `DetailsView` in output on selecting 'Select' option
here is the code image 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YyUq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the `DataSet` not [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx). So you could either do this:

```
da.Fill(ds,"tbl");
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Or use a `DataTable` instead:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Also you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Something like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Pm where user_id=@userId", con1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", (String)Session["uid"]);
```

Also have a look at this: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue`() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: sir,
actually, in the grid-view, the data is showing correctly but I want in selecting a particular row on the 'select' option the 'detail view' will be opened and which is linked with the 'grid view'.I also Attached the image of that code in my question please see it and suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set DataTable instead of DataSet

```
GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Pm"];
```

Answer (score 0):

@PIYUSH Itspk please check query and replace

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Pm where user_id=" +Session["uid"].tostring()+ ", con1);
```

i think its help you if any other query please notify me